# Without using django forms how to validate and save form data

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Suppose I have a 'question' model with two fields - title and content

Now think of question creation form. Using django forms I can display it to template and validate using is_valid method.

But I don't want to use django inbuilt forms. I want to write my forms in handwritten html and send it to server using POST method.

How will validation and saving to database will work in this case?

[I am doing something similar to this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57271744/how-to-validate-template-versioned-form-fields-in-django-without-using-django-fo) but I am not satisfied with the existing answers

Comment: Why make more work for yourself? You can still render fields manually. See the section [Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually) in the documentation. You can also add a few attributes to the field by changing the fields definition in the form. If you still don't like doing that you can always use these great packages to customize rendering of fields [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.org/project/django-widget-tweaks/) and [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat  Actually I want to use a markdown editor instead of django forms textarea to get the input from user. Kind of like stackoverflow's editor when answering questions. Django defaults to textarea and my markdown editor is a third party JS package.

Comment: That just implies you need a custom widget. Check this question [Django: How to build a custom form widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707192/django-how-to-build-a-custom-form-widget)

Comment: I'd recommend creating the form, not use it for the html presentation if you don't want to (although I'd probably build a widget), and utilize the forms validation and benefits of sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

In your views:

```
import Model
Param = request.post.get('param') 
Model.objects.create(field=param)
```

Just like that,  you have saved that to the model.

Comment: That's not a very great method. You are losing out on cleaning and validation of the data. The OP's question mainly was _"How will validation and saving to database will work in this case?"_

Comment: I see your suggestions and they are good. But he says he doesn't want to use django forms.